# Closed forms and trajectories of vector fields

Tags: differential-topology, dg.differential-geometry, differentials

This question is inspired by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107692/closed-dual-of-vector-fields) recent one and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48491/why-are-differential-forms-called-closed-and-exact) one; I hope it's not too elementary.

Let $M$ be a (closed) smooth manifold and $X$ a vector field on $M$. Fix any Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ and let $X^{\flat}=g(X,\cdot)$ be the metric-dual differential form of $X$.

> If $dX^{\flat}=0$, what can be said about the trajectories of $X$?

Comment: For example, $X$ can't have contractible (or, in fact, nullhomologous) closed orbits. This has been said in some answer to the first question you linked.

Comment: @MarcoGolla: there, it was assumed $X$ never zero. But, ok, it may be a good hypothesis to add to my question.

Comment: Have you looked at Michael Farber's "Topology of closed one-forms" book? I believe he discusses related problems in the last chapter.